# icarousel with cocos2d issue

Tags: ipad, carousel

Every body i am integrating icarousel with cocos2d using uiviewwrapper and after that i have done with icarousel is working fine in simulator but on ipad it make some problem that is its first and last options are responding normally as it does but in between options uibuttons are not responding when selected and thay are working when that are at some specific angle not in front view .I have searched alot but i could not find any solution for that as there is not a single warning or error when app builds.
All suggestions will be welcomed. Thanks

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/85

Answer (score 2):

In the appDelegate function delete the line

```
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];
```

and replace the same with

```
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];
```

setting the `[CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink]` will cause unexpected behaviour in iCarousel.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Cocos may be interfering with the UITapGestureRecognizer that iCarousel uses to intercept taps and forward them to the item views.

That would explain why you can tap the side views but not the frontmost view, since it's gestures are treated differently.

Try poking around in the code and adding some breakpoints to the gesture handling logic to see if you can see where it's failing.

Alternatively, send me a working code example and I'll take a look.